# Remove margins between TableRow

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Hello I'm new to android studio and I'm making a calculator app. I want to position the buttons next to each other but I am unable to remove the margin between the TableRows. I set `android:layout_margin="0dp"` in both of my rows yet I still have a gap between them.
Here is my xml: https://pastebin.com/YuLUJg8v

EDIT: I have the height of the buttons set to match parent but for whatever reason it does still not take up the entire height of the row. It seems the problem lies with the buttons not the tablerow

[image]

Comment: I am still needing help with this issue if anyone has some insight

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by setting the top and bottom margins of each button to -6